# How can I tell if WorkManager is initialized?

Tags: android, android-workmanager

WorkManager is supposed to have an [`isInitialized()` static method](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/work/WorkManager#isInitialized()) that "Provides a way to check if WorkManager is initialized in this process", but I can't find it in the code (v2.7.1).

Is there another way to do this without having to catch an exception if it's not initialized yet?

Comment: You can use the property reference to check if workManager is initialized or not like this. 
 `if(::workManager.isInitialized){ // carry on } else { // do something }`

Answer (score 0):

This function was added in January 2022, and it is included in [WorkManager 2.8.0-alpha02](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/work#2.8.0-alpha02). This is the reason why you cannot find this API in version 2.7.1.

[`isInitialized()`](https://github.com/androidx/androidx/blob/ec7da70327161a4911a358709701ea5388be3f1a/work/work-runtime/src/main/java/androidx/work/WorkManager.java#L218) is defined in the `WorkManager` abstract class and the [current implementation](https://github.com/androidx/androidx/blob/ec7da70327161a4911a358709701ea5388be3f1a/work/work-runtime/src/main/java/androidx/work/impl/WorkManagerImpl.java#L149) checks if there's already a WorkManager instance,